# Conten-Length header in response is not present

Tags: yesod

I have noticed that my yesod site does not respond with Content-Length header.

I have tried to add it with addHeader (in the Handler) with no result.

I am sure that I am missing something very fundamental, but do not see it.

My handlers are Handler Html handlers. I have suceeded adding a custom header using addHeader right before defaultLayout...

Answer (score 2):

Content-Length is a special header, in the sense that its presence when incorrect will mess up your response. A number of different components will end up stripping it out. My guess in this case is that your response is being GZIP compressed, which necessarily removes the content-length header.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I doubt it! I have tested it with wget directly to the development instance ... and do not see who might be gziping it! If I'm wrong, any idea of how to find who is gziping and how to deactivate it?

Comment: If you use `toWaiApp`, then gzip is turned on. You can use `toWaiAppPlain` instead. Another test would be to see what happens when you return a strict `ByteString`. But what you haven't explained is why any of this matters.

Comment: Thanks again. I am already using toWaiAppPlain. I try to explain the situation: this seems to matter when there is a proxy in the middle, the proxy receives a response as 'text/plain' without content-length and does not close the connection...

Comment: I have the same problem - I try to send an mp3 file to jPlayer (jplayer.org) which needs the content length. Unfortunately, Content-Length is not set and I cannot set it manually. The file is definitely NOT zipped. No solution for this one?

Comment: The issue is that I can't reproduce the problem. For example, the following program returns a content-length just fine, when requested with GZIP transfer-encoding: http://lpaste.net/112159

Comment: Make that *without GZIP transfer-encoding*.

Comment: I just checked your program. Indeed, it returns content-length. But in my case, I use a scaffolded application. I just created a new scaffolded site (with sqlite, for what it's worth) and did a request to localhost:3000. Result was: Length: not specified. Yesod version: 1.4.0